# style sheet header on Page Templates

Tags: templates

What is the reason for using a style sheet header on page templates, where critcal values are assigned within a comments block in php, instead of just declaring constants, objects, or some other php structure?

The style sheet header is like this:

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Fifteen Child
Theme URI:  *
Description: Twenty Fifteen Child Theme
Author: John Doe
Author URI:  *
Template: twentyfifteen
Version: 1.0.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI:*  
Tags: light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout,     accessibility-ready
Text Domain: twenty-fifteen-child
*/
```

What is the advantage of the active code in the comments block over putting those values in an array, example below? Is there no php code that would be better than putting live values into the comments?

```
$child_theme_definition=array();
$child_theme_definition['theme_name']='Twenty Fifteen Child';
$child_theme_definition['theme_uri']=''*;
$child_theme_definition['Description']='Twenty Fifteen Child Theme';
$child_theme_definition['Author']='John Doe';
$child_theme_definition['Author URI']=''*;
$child_theme_definition['Template']='twentyfifteen';
$child_theme_definition['Version']='1.0.0';
$child_theme_definition['License']='GNU General Public License v2 or later';
$child_theme_definition['License URI']=''*;
$child_theme_definition['Tags']='light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
Text Domain: twenty-fifteen-child';
```

*urls omitted because my new account is not allowed to include more than two urls in a post.

Answer (score 2):

The headers have to be read without the files being executed. The files are parsed to extract the headers without executing the php code they contain.

Comment: why? What difference does it make? Is this a common practice?

Comment: I cannot come up with a reason why it would be necessary for the headers not to execute something. Something is executing on the headers, reading them into variables, parsing them, using the results. Instead of putting a header in a comment block of the style.css, why not have theme.config file,  similar to wp-config.php? What is the problem caused by the headers being script that can execute?

Comment: Why are themes the only part of the system requiring non-executing headers placed in comment blocks?  Why disrupt the normal function of comments, which is to have no effect on what software does? These headers cannot possibly be the only way to provide this the information needed about child themes, and this way is confusing.

Comment: the files containing the headers to create a child themes do not contain php. They are css files.

Comment: You have template files that contain PHP that can only be run within a certain context- when that specific page is being viewed. You need to be able to read the headers without running that code, so they can't be executed as PHP files in any other context. CSS files can't contain PHP, they would be invalid CSS files.

Comment: Or perhaps an analogy- you have a box of fireworks that each produce a different color. You need to know which color each firework is without having to actually launch it into the sky.

Comment: Why not put the information into a theme config file instead? The only file required to make a child theme is style.css with one of these headers in it. There is no php to avoid running in the css file. So why is the header put in comments in the css file?  Do you have any authority for the rationale you are suggesting? What I would like to know is why the WordPress development team sticks with this arrangement. It is not possible that this arrangement is the only possible way to make the software work. So why was this picked over other possible choices?

Comment: The fireworks analogy is nonsense. It always is possible to read values with php and set variables and constants to those values without causing a problem downstream, by using variable or constant names that are not already used for something else. Can you provide a code sample showing why these headers in comments are necessary? I'll provide a a modification to WordPress that replaces one of these these headers with a config file to show it works.

Comment: The current scheme requires no specific language and that a file only be readable. You are suggesting php be required, and the file be executable. You are only limiting the use of this data and decreasing security  while providing no real benefit in terms of how this data is actually used. Your local WP install is not the only code that uses that data.

Comment: And the fireworks analogy was in regards to page template headers- you can't execute some PHP in a page template without executing the whole template, and those headers have to be read in order to generate a list of assignable page templates.

Comment: Milo, thank you for explaining the benefits of the current scheme. What uses the header data besides the local WP install?

Comment: The theme and plugin repositories use that data as well.

Comment: I edited the answer, attempting to elaborate using information provided in the comments.

Comment: @ScottyJakes I've rejected your edit. If you've found an answer by yourself, please do not misrepresent other's answers but create your own.

Comment: Milo, I am not going to mark your answer as the answer unless you elaborate. I took a shot at editing it and even though I was attempting to put the information you provided into the answer, it was rejected because it was misrepresenting your answer. I think I understand the answer now, and I think the answer I wrote is correct and well written, but no one agrees. The answer you have provided is poor, because there are ways of achieving the results you mention that do not entail putting operational, required information into comments. Why is using the comments the only or best solution?

Comment: @MaxYudin, how about editing my answer, explaining why it's wrong, or something besides REJECT as a contribution to having an answer? It was helpful that you explained why my edits of Milo's answer were not the right way to be editing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for using headers placed within comments is it gives WordPress core and WordPress libraries for themes and plugins a way read data they  need in a secure and simple way.  Alternatives, such as putting the data in configuration files, are seen as either more complicated, less secure or both. The WordPress development team puts more weight on "simple and secure" than on keeping required elements out of the comments within files.